# how to configure The SP name in azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I configured azure AD as an identity provider for my organization's application

whenever i try to access the application its redirecting the request to azure login. But I am getting a bad request error and its showing the below message

The SP name qualifier 'abc.xxxx.com' is not valid.

I am not sure if i have done something wrong.

Below is my configuration

```
SIGN ON URL
https://abc.xxxx.com/myapp/saml/ssoRequest?ticket=kcflmlmnpgg

ISSUER URL
https://abc.xxxx.com

REPLY URL

https://abc.xxxx.com/myapp/ssoResponse
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was when i was submitting the SAML request I was not prepending the 'http://' in the service provider name